# Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, beancreationexception

I have developed a Spring Boot application with PostgreSQL.

I am trying to run my Spring Boot application, but I don't know why I am getting these two errors:

1. > Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2. > j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

And also the application is get shutdown as soon as it started.

```
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
 o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nextuple</groupId>
    <artifactId>oms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oms</name>
    <description>Project for OMS</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port:9090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/orderdetails
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

//main

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class OmsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OmsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper(){
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error creating bean with name and Singleton bean creation not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017746/error-creating-bean-with-name-and-singleton-bean-creation-not-allowed)

Comment: You need to look earlier in the logs. These errors are almost always symptoms of your application being terminated because of an earlier error.

Comment: I resolved this issue. Thank you guys for your quick response

Comment: what was the resolution?